USB C for both Power and Data in Peripheral Devices
USB C now has two main functions: power delivery and data.
I am making USB peripherals that need both USB power and data support.
In my case, I can specify power using just the two 5.1K resistors with a C connector.
The problem is that many users will still want to use A to C cables, which in my case is insufficient. (I want 900 mA < i < 3A at 5V). In this case, a PD charger would be needed.
One solution is to have two USB C connectors, one power and one data. This is a bit of a kludge when you have a USB C direct connection that can do both. This suggests some kind of reasonable power management on the data USB connector, so that if there is sufficient power, the second USB power connector could be ignored.
I was thinking that maybe the "Power" USB C could use a FET switch to disconnect the Data USB power if it is plugged in, otherwise power would come from just the "Data" USB
This seems to me that this will be a common situation given that the EU would like to eliminate all non USB C wall warts.
So my question is what approaches have others used? Does anyone have a circuit that they have vetted?

I was looking at the TI TPS2117 Power Mux. This is rated for 1.6V to 5.5V and 4A.
If the Vbus from the "Power" USB is the primary supply, it is automatically selected. If it is not plugged in and powered, power would come from the "Data" USB.
This works the same way battery backup works.
